# Python Wrap Class Method

Tags: python, class, methods, wrapper

I'm trying to create an object with a run method that will be wrapped by a `_wrap_run method`. I'd like to be able to call the method and it's wrapper by simply typing `instance.run()` and I'd like to be able to subclass the object so I can override the `run()` method and have it still execute the wrapper.

More simply put, I want people to be able to subclass A and override `run()` but still have calls to the `run()` method execute the wrapper function.

I'm having some difficulty with the mechanics of this. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding this approach?

```
class A:

    def run(self):
        print "Run A"
        return True

    def _wrap_run(self):
        print "PRE"
        return_value = self.run()
        print "POST"
        return return_value

    run = property(_wrap_run)


a = A()
a.run()
"""
Should Print: 
PRE
Run A
POST
"""


class B(A):

    def run(self):
        print "Run B"
        return True

b = B()
b.run()
"""
Should Print: 
PRE
Run B
POST
"""
```

Comment: What is the point of `_wrap_run`?  Is this supposed to be some kind of decorator?  What's wrong with using a decorator for this?

Comment: He doesn't want to have to decorate all the derived classes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a Metaclass.

```
class MetaClass(type):
    @staticmethod
    def wrap(run):
        """Return a wrapped instance method"""
        def outer(self):
            print "PRE",
            return_value = run(self)
            print "POST"
            return return_value
        return outer
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        """If the class has a 'run' method, wrap it"""
        if 'run' in attrs:
            attrs['run'] = cls.wrap(attrs['run'])
        return super(MetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class MyClass(object):
    """Use MetaClass to make this class"""
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
    def run(self): print 'RUN',

myinstance = MyClass()

# Prints PRE RUN POST
myinstance.run()
```

Now if other people subclass `MyClass`, they will still get their `run()` methods wrapped.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way: make `run` the wrapper, and a private method be the overrideable one.

```
class A(object):
    def run(self):
        print "PRE"
        return_value = self._inner_run()
        print "POST"
        return return_value

    def _inner_run(self):
        print "Run A"
        return True

class B(A):
    def _inner_run(self):
        print "Run B"
        return True
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'd like to make it so the person implementing run() in the subclass doesn't have to worry about making extra calls and depend on them to properly add the function call.  Plus the underscored wrapper function is doing some maintenance work that I'd like to keep 'hidden' from the child class.  Though I don't know if what I am asking will work...

Comment: @JoeJ: Document the interface properly, and it won't matter if subclass has to override `run` or something else.

Comment: @Joe: it's very common to let user override `_run`, see [FormEncode `_to_python`](http://formencode.org/Validator.html?highlight=_to_python) for example, instead of `run`

Answer (score 2):

What other folks do

```
class A:
   def do_run( self ):
       """Must be overridden."""
       raise NotImplementedError
   def run( self, *args, **kw ):
       """Must not be overridden.
       You were warned.
       """
       print "PRE"
       return_value = self.do_run(*args, **kw)
       print "POST"
       return return_value

class B(A):
    def do_run(self):
        print "Run B"
        return True
```

That's usually sufficient.

If you want to worry about someone "breaking" this, stop now.  Don't waste time worrying.

It's Python.  We're all adults here.  All the malicious sociopaths will break all you code by copying it, changing it, and then breaking it.  No matter what you do, they'll just copy your code and modify it to break the clever bits.

Everyone else will read your comment and stick by your rules.  If they want to use your module/package/framework, they will cooperate.

Comment: `run()` needs to call `do_run()` which needs to accept arguments.

Comment: Thanks S.Lott.  That seems like a strait-forward approach.  Ya, I suppose a few well placed comments would be sufficient.

Comment: @Joe J: They **are** sufficient.  There's nothing else you can do, really.  Anything more complex is just a maintenance headache.  And no matter how much extra code you write, someone is always going to mess with it.  So write the least code you can get away with.

Comment: In your example objects of `class A` can't be used, only its descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Here a while later, but if the method is a normal method, you could just use a regular decorator. Take the example below, which is a simplified SSH connector.

```
class SSH:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connected = False

    def connect(self) -> None:
        self.connected = True

    def call_only_if_connected(self) -> None:
        print("foo")
```

In this example, we only want the method `call_only_if_connected` to be called, as the name implies, if the SSH object that it is instantiated to has `self.connected=True`.

We can define a normal wrapper *outside* the class, and since `self`, or the instance of the class, is always passed as the first arg (`args[0]`), we can just make out check there. Consider:

```
def assert_connected(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if not args[0].connected:
            raise RuntimeError("attempted to call a method that requires a connection without an established connection")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

class SSH:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connected = False

    def connect(self) -> None:
        self.connected = True

    @assert_connected
    def call_only_if_connected(self) -> None:
        print("foo")
```

Note in the above example that an `AttributeError` will be thrown if the object does not have a `connected` property, so it is important to define `connected=False` as soon as possible (i.e., as soon as you instantiate the object in `__init__`).

You could handle the improper connection how you'd like; in my example above, I am throwing a `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is basically a [decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), so why not go ahead and implement `_wrap_run` as a decorator and apply it when subclassing the function?

Comment: I was thinking about making a decorator out of it, but is there a way to do the decorating in the parent class so the person implementing any child classes doesn't have to add the decorator each time?

Comment: Nope, that's against what python stands for

Comment: I think it's __exactly__ what Python stands for. How is it different than duck typing, or context managers? I can write 'run()' in a straightforward manner, and the metaclass takes care of the details.

Comment: @agf well IMO it's not pythonic if someone subclasses your class and it turns out that the function _you_ implemented does not work as expected because of things going on "behind the scenes". Cat Plus Plus's solution, for example, does not do things behind the scenes: the programmer that implements the function _knows_ it will be run as-is, but also that it will be run through another function.

Comment: If I write a class that doesn't work in __any way__, it's not good. Messing up the wrapper function isn't any different from messing up `__init__`, or `__repr__`, or any other method that isn't overridden. They are all expected to 'just work' by subclasses.